# Appium - Android Inspector crashes on real devices

Tags: android, appium

I was trying to run appium using a real device Galaxy Nexus with Android Version 4.2.1, everything is ok. But appium crashes if I click the inspector button, I'm using the latest version of Appium

[image]

[image]

I'm not seeing errors on the log,

```
2016-01-18 20:09:51:071 - info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
2016-01-18 20:09:51:071 - info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
2016-01-18 20:09:51:078 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
2016-01-18 20:09:51:079 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2016-01-18 20:09:51:081 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
2016-01-18 20:09:51:081 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp","status":0}
2016-01-18 20:09:51:083 - info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
2016-01-18 20:09:51:084 - info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
2016-01-18 20:09:51:095 - info: [debug] Getting device API level
2016-01-18 20:09:51:096 - info: [debug] executing cmd: /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 014E054A0F012008 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
2016-01-18 20:09:51:101 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
2016-01-18 20:09:51:101 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2016-01-18 20:09:51:102 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
2016-01-18 20:09:51:102 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":false,"status":0}
2016-01-18 20:09:51:126 - info: [debug] Device is at API Level 17
2016-01-18 20:09:51:127 - info: [debug] executing cmd: /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 014E054A0F012008 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.example.hybridtestapp/com.example.hybridtestapp.MainActivity"
2016-01-18 20:09:51:947 - info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.example.hybridtestapp" and activity "com.example.hybridtestapp.MainActivity" to be focused
2016-01-18 20:09:51:948 - info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
2016-01-18 20:09:51:949 - info: [debug] executing cmd: /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 014E054A0F012008 shell "dumpsys window windows"
2016-01-18 20:09:52:104 - info: [debug] executing cmd: /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 014E054A0F012008 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
2016-01-18 20:09:52:140 - info: [debug] Device is at release version 4.2.1
2016-01-18 20:09:52:140 - info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
2016-01-18 20:09:52:141 - info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 7200 secs
2016-01-18 20:09:52:146 - info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
2016-01-18 20:09:52:146 - info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
2016-01-18 20:09:52:153 - info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/moisessiles/Downloads/Hybridtestapp.zip","sessionOverride":true,"noReset":true,"launch":true,"log":"/Users/moisessiles/GAPProjects/Appium/appium.log","androidPackage":"com.example.hybridtestapp","androidActivity":"com.example.hybridtestapp.MainActivity","deviceName":"Galaxy Nexus","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.2","automationName":"Appium","defaultCommandTimeout":7200,"debugLogSpacing":true}
2016-01-18 20:09:52:153 - info: Console LogLevel: debug
2016-01-18 20:09:52:153 - info: File LogLevel: debug
```

Comment: what you doing is just launching the app, and clicking on inspector at that time it is crashing right? then write some test cases for that app, while execution running parallely click on inspector.

Comment: try with device having os >=5.0, it should be ok.

Comment: it is an Appium bug? I need to use the 4.2.1 device

Answer (score 0):

Inspecter crashes for <4.2. Its a known bug in Appium. Try upgrading to 5.0